# Assistance with key error in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

So first off I want to thank everybody for helping me previously. After digging deeper into the previous problems of my understanding , I had a lot of people assist me with a better understanding. So I apologize in advance to for asking so many questions, but its honestly how I learn and I feel as though it will make me a much better coder in the longer run.

In saying that I understand the issues I am having with the code on the bottom. Its basically because I am removing the `key=item` when the item is picked up. Then if the user accidently uses the same "Get "Item"" or anything revolving around "Get" it just comes back with an error saying `key error: Item`

So I was wondering if anybody had any ideas on how to fix this?

````
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print("Halo Text Adventure Game")
    print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be eaten by Gravemind.")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


def movement_between_locations(location, action, rooms):
    location = rooms[location][action]
    return location


def get_item(location, action, rooms, equipment):
    equipment.append(rooms[location]['item'])
    del rooms[location]['item']
    return rooms, equipment, location , action

def main():
    rooms = {
        'Halo': {'South': 'The Silent Cartographer', 'North': 'Assault on the Control Room',
                 'East': 'Pillar of Autumn', 'West': 'The Library'},
        'The Silent Cartographer': {'North': 'Halo', 'East': '343 Guilty Spark', 'item': 'Camo'},
        '343 Guilty Spark': {'West': 'The Silent Cartographer', 'item': 'Energy Sword'},
        'The Maw': {'South': 'Pillar of Autumn', 'item': 'Gravemind'},
        'The Library': {'East': 'Halo', 'item': 'Frag Grenade'},
        'Assault on the Control Room': {'South': 'Halo', 'East': 'Two Betrayals', 'item': 'Rocket Launcher'},
        'Two Betrayals': {'West': 'Assault on the Control Room', 'item': 'Plasma Grenade'},
        'Pillar of Autumn': {'West': 'Halo', 'North': 'The Maw', 'item': 'Over Shield'},
    }

    location = 'Halo'
    equipment = []
    show_instructions()

    while True:

        # Checking user_action and connecting to new room, or if they typed get item, item is received
        if location == "The Maw":
            # User wins
            if len(equipment) == 6:
                print("You won")
                break
            else:
                print("You lost")
                break
        # Display players room, equipment,
        print("You are in the " + location)
        print(equipment)
        print("-" * 20)
        # This will tell user if there is an item in the room
        if location != 'The Maw' and 'item' in rooms[location].keys():
            print('You see the {}'.format(rooms[location]['item']))
        action = input("Enter your move:").title().split()
        if len(action) >= 2 and action[1] in rooms[location].keys():
            location = movement_between_locations(location, action[1], rooms)
            continue
        elif len(action[0]) == 3 and action[0] == "Get" and ' '.join(action[1:]) in rooms[location]['item']:
            print("You picked up the {}!".format(rooms[location]['item']))
            print('-' * 20)
            get_item(location, action, rooms, equipment)
            continue
        else:
            print("invalid input")
            continue


main() ```
````

Comment: Your question has a lot of apologies and introduction, but very little information on the actual problem here. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: As stated above when running the line of code , I recieve a key error for "Item" after user picked up the item and the function deletes the code key from the dictionary. I was wondering for solutions to that specific problem. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to either check if a room has an `'item'` attribute (`'item' in rooms[location]`) before interacting with it, or change your code so that `'item'` can be an empty list (as I'm assuming a room might also have more than one item?)

Comment: No, each room has only one item. I am working with what you gave me so far , and I will get back to you. So from my understanding your saying because I have it with a condition statement, its a problem because its interacting with nothing, so simply check for it before interacting with it. I will try to see how to do that. 

If possible would you be able to post an answer on how you expect it? I am still going at it

Answer (score 0):

You can check before get it:

```
def get_item(location, action, rooms, equipment):
    try:
       item = rooms[location]['item']
    except:
       return # do something here
    equipment.append(item)
    del rooms[location]['item']
    return rooms, equipment, location , action
```

Comment: Hi Bichanna, Thanks for the attempt but unfortunately this did not fix the problem. In the bottom this is what I get 
`  File "C:\Users\19738\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\HaloText(Beta).py", line 62, in main
    elif len(action[0]) == 3 and action[0] == "Get" and ' '.join(action[1:]) in rooms[location]['item']:
KeyError: 'item' `

Comment: @ChristosNikitopoulos I'm not sure how this could raise a `KeyError`. Are you sure you are running this snippet correctly?

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes, I found the error it was on line ` elif len(action[0]) == 3 and action[0] == "Get" and ' '.join(action[1:]) in rooms[location]['item']:` 

So apparently it was because it was utilizing the operator `in` and not using `==`  making the code look as such `        
elif action[0] == "Get" and 'item' in rooms[location].keys():
            if ' '.join(action[1:]) == rooms[location]['item']:`

Which also generated another error not seen previously. The moment user typed "get" it would retrieve item because of the misused operator. As long as "Some" is true then it would conduct get

Answer (score 0):

When removing items from a dictionary, you can use the `dict.pop` method, which contains a default argument for what to return if the key isn't present:

```py
def get_item(location, action, rooms, equipment):
    # Gets removed from the dictionary here
    # and if the key doesn't exist, it returns the second arg (None)
    item = rooms[location].pop('item', None)

    if item is not None:
        equipment.append(item)

    return rooms, equipment, location , action
```

However, you don't actually need most of your arguments. You just need `rooms` and `location`, and you can just return the `item` and append it to `equipment` later:

```py
# Get rid of unnecessary arguments
def get_item(location, rooms):
    # Gets removed from the dictionary here
    # and if the key doesn't exist, it returns the second arg (None)
    return rooms[location].pop('item', None)


# Wherever you call `get_item` is how this code gets used
item = get_item(rooms, location)

if item is not None:
    equipment.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you I will check this the moment I get to the PC! Please standby haha

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work either. It provides different error because it doesn't have the position arguments for those values. 

I believe I would have to rearrange alot of code to make the 2nd one work . The First code provides same errors as before "Key Error"
File "C:\Users\19738\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\HaloText(Beta).py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\19738\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\HaloText(Beta).py", line 66, in main
    item = get_item(rooms, location)
TypeError: get_item() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'rooms' and 'equipment'

Comment: Are you paying attention to the code you are running? Read the error message. It looks like you just copied my second solution without reading about the additional changes you need to make

Comment: Try the first solution, you shouldn't have to make any changes

Comment: Yes I posted a response above @C.nivs above. The problem was the operator on line 66. I had to nest it further to provide necessary result. Would you mind one day sharing with me on a private session on how you came up with your explanation? Id really like to hear it as I am still learning and I am extremely eager to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You said that in your game, a room has one item at most, or none. It then makes sense to reflect that in your data model:

```py
def main():
    rooms = {
        'Halo': {'South': 'The Silent Cartographer', 'North': 'Assault on the Control Room',
                 'East': 'Pillar of Autumn', 'West': 'The Library', 'item': None},
        'The Silent Cartographer': {'North': 'Halo', 'East': '343 Guilty Spark', 'item': 'Camo'},
    ...
```

Note how the `'item'` dictionary key for the `'Halo'` room has a value of `None` (not `'None'`), indicating there's no item there.

Now you can use:

```
def get_item(location, action, rooms, equipment):
    if item is not None:
        equipment.append(rooms[location]['item'])
        rooms[location]['item'] = None
    return rooms, equipment, location, action
```

By setting the value to `None`, but not removing the key, you can still check the key later to check for `None`, or assign a new item if the player can drop one. Similarly, you could just say that "not having an 'item' key" means there is no item. In that case, you wouldn't change the room definition and you could just:

```
def get_item(location, action, rooms, equipment):
    if 'item' not in rooms[location]:
        equipment.append(rooms[location]['item'])
        del(rooms[location]['item'])
    return rooms, equipment, location, action
```

Just make sure you always check for the presence of keys that might not be there, wherever you try to read them in your code.

Of course, you could add some more code to write a message if the player tries to pick up an item that's not there, etc. But I assume the idea is clear.